# How can I extract some variables from the data using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data file shows number of theft per year for each state

under the state variable there are all the states of the US
however I need only to choose from that column(the state) the following
Say I need only to choose Alabama, Arizona, Iowa.
How can I do that with `ggplot2`

I think there is a way to do it by facet_wrap
the `code facet_wrap(~State,scale="free_y)`

I tried to change `~State to ~("Alabama")+("Arizona")`
but was not helpful

```
ggplot(aes(x = log(Burglary), y = log(Motor.vehicle.theft)), colour =Year,data=fbiwide) +
  facet_wrap(~State,scale = "free_y") + 
  geom_point()
```

I need to pick only three states to be graphed so I can compare between them instead of getting them all

Comment: Where can we find the dataset `fbiwide`?

Comment: This is a subsetting problem: `i <- fbiwide$State %in% c("Alabama", "Arizona", "Iowa"); fbi3states <- fbiwide[i, ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `filter` `fbiwide` based on the `State` variable. Try something like:

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(aes(x = log(Burglary), y = log(Motor.vehicle.theft)), colour = Year,
       data = filter(fbiwide, State %in% c("Alabama", "Arizona", "Iowa"))) +
        facet_wrap(~State, scale = "free_y") + 
        geom_point()
```